# Angularjs, problema con ng.repeat al hacer push

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, scope

Tengo un problema con angular, este es mi codigo:

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Insertar presupuesto</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seleccionarp">Buscar producto</button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div id="seleccionarp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">

                                    <!-- Modal content-->
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Seleccione su producto</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <label for="Buscar cliente  ">Buscar producto:</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" id="buscarproducto" ng-model="busqueda[queryBy]" value="" placeholder="Buscar" />
                                            <div>
                                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                                                        <th>Color</th>
                                                        <th>Talle</th>
                                                        <th>Stock</th>
                                                        <th>Precio</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tbody ng-repeat="emp in posts | filter:busqueda">
                                                        <tr ng-click="comprar(emp)" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                            <td>{{emp.nombre_producto}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{emp.color}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{emp.talle}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{emp.stock}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{emp.precio | currency}}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                                        <th>Precio</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody ng-repeat="p in carrito track by $index">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_producto[]" value="{{p.id_producto}}" ng-model="p.id_producto" class="form-control">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="color[]" value="{{p.color}}" ng-model="p.color" class="form-control">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="talle[]" value="{{p.talle}}" ng-model="p.talle" class="form-control">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="nombre_producto[]" ng-model="p.nombre_producto" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" name="stock[]" ng-model="p.stock" value="1" onClick="this.select();" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="precio[]" ng-model="p.precio" onClick="this.select();" class="form-control" value=""></td>
                                        <td>{{p.stock * p.precio | currency}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index)">Eliminar</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <h2>Total:${{total()}}</h2><input type="hidden" name="total_remito" value="{{total()}}">
                            <button type="submit" name="button">guardar</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

AngularJS

```js
app.controller("ctrlremitos", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.carrito = [];

        $scope.clienteasignado = [];

        $scope.clientes = [];

        $scope.busqueda = {}

        $scope.busquedaclientes = {}

        $scope.queryBy = '$'

        $scope.newPost = {};

        $http.get(base_url + "venta/get_productos").success(function(data, timeout) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        }).error(function(err) {
        })

        $http.get(base_url + "venta/get_clientes").success(function(data) {
            $scope.clientes = data;
        }).error(function(err) {
        })

        $scope.comprar = function(_item, index) {
            $scope.carrito.push(_item)
        }

        $scope.asignarcliente = function(_item) {
            $scope.clienteasignado.push(_item)
        }

        $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.carrito.splice(index, 1);
            },

            $scope.total = function() {
                var total = 0;
                angular.forEach($scope.carrito, function(p) {
                    total += p.stock * p.precio;
                })
                return total;
            }

    });
```

El problema está en que cuando selecciono un producto, hace el push pero el valor siempre es el valor del stock, lo que quiero es que cuando se haga ese push se cambie el valor de stock siempre por 1. Otra cosa que noto es que cuando cambio el valor en el campo "stock", tambien se cambia en el array de la busqueda de productos, no se que hacer :( llevo dias intentando hacer que esto funcione correctamente, espero que me iluminen el camino.

Saludos

Comment: https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter Dejo el repositorio del sistema por si a alguien le interesa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicos lo logré mi problema era el two-bind, olvide que si usaba esta expresion "::" en la variable determinada solo hace one-bind, luego en el campo "stock" utilice ng-init con valor 1 y listo >(, problemas solucionado, muchas gracias por ser tan atentos. Dejo un link del commit

https://github.com/outthesystem/facturacion-codeigniter/commit/5c4e8737d0e0b1732ba127e60fb46f1065344e03